# public static element changed automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio

first of all. sorry for my bad english. I'm new in visual studio and c#. usually I code in java. I tried to make simple windows forms project. after that I put a textbox into it. and I changed that textbox from public(auto generated) into public static. but when I see the design view version and if I double click that textbox, it becomes public again. what can I do if I still want that textbox stay static without manually change?

Comment: You don't want form elements to be static because they should belong to a specific instantiation of the form. Why are you so insistent on changing it to static?

Comment: I hope you are not planning to do this from another form or another class: `var text = Form1.textbox1.Text`. because you will get a null reference exception even if Visual Studio left it alone and did not change it back to instance field. Or if you did it like the answer has suggested. Or I hope you are not planning to do this on my team.

Comment: You shouldn't make form fields static in Java, and you shouldn't in .net either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Forms controls must be instance, not static, members for it to work properly. That is why the designer is forcing the removal of the static.

I assume you want to share that value else where in the application, if your going to use the legacy Windows Forms, and not something more modern and supported like WPF or UWP, I highly recommend using the [Model-View-Presenter](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/mvp-design-pattern-for-window-forms/) pattern.